# Trying to remember software that self-documents SOAP/REST API

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, documentation

I'm trying to remember the name of the piece of software that would help you self-document your REST and SOAP API's as well as other things. It has a wiki that would go along with it as well...

Does anyone remember it? It's open source

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out; it's called [**enunciate**](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/)